# Adding new Activity in Android failed in Android studio 2.2.3

Tags: android, android-activity, layout

the first image has main>new> activity option

[image]

the second image doesn't have main>new> activity option

[image]

the first image is from udacity tutorials with older version of Android studio. Second image is my Android studio latest version 2.2.3.
I want to add a new layout but the option is not there.

Comment: Notice the difference between the two images where you right click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on Android Studio, your second image to create a layout file choose the option "Android Resource File"

Right Click -> New -> Android resource file

on the window that will appear choose Layout

Answer (score 0):

The difference is not between the versions of Android Studio. It is between where you right click. You seem to have right clicked on the project. Instead, you need to click on the `app` module.

Comment: I have doubt that app module is absent I imported this from git . I will post that pic .

Comment: @yanamalachaitanya The point is that you right clicked in the wrong place. Look closely at the screenshot from Udacity. They did not click on the top-level project folder like you did. When you create a new Android Studio project, the module has a default name of `app`. Since you imported a project it might have another name instead. Modules have a folder icon with a blue tea cup.

Answer (score 0):

It's not about the clicking on wrong place  I think it's an update problem now the problem is cleared.[problem solved so now anywhere I click the activity option is showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9k4ui.png)